# how to convert the post response to presentable form in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, post

[homepage screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBXHP.jpg)

[result screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4c2S.jpg)

when onpressed search button i get the result screen like shown in the above picture

i need to present the data from the above list in this form given image below

[result screen prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKXMO.jpg)

presently the code of the result screen is given below

resultpage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class output extends StatelessWidget {
  final String apiresult;

  output(this.apiresult);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Result Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(apiresult),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

can anyone give the code to arrange the data as in the above design please

Answer (score 0):

```
//for answer:    
Text(apiresult["data"][0]),
   
//for explanation 
Text(apiresult["data"][1]),
```

for image you can use `apiresult["data"][2]` but is encoded base64. so you have to decode it to image.